# SLD combine interpolate+categorize function and pass threshold

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld

In my requirement I have a float atribute (value) containing values between 0 and 10.

I want to use the interpolate function to color values between 0 and the threshold=5 in green colors and to interpolate the values between 5 and 10 with red colors. So it's somehow a combination of the interpolate and the categorize function of SLD. Is that possible?

```
<CssParameter name="stroke">
  <ogc:Function name="Interpolate">
                     <ogc:PropertyName>VALUE</ogc:PropertyName>
                     <ogc:Literal>-9999</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Literal>#000000</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Literal>#000000</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Literal>#A51C1C</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Literal>#FF9A9A</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Literal>#00FF00</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Literal>color</ogc:Literal>
```

Additionally I want to use the env parameter function of geoserver to pass the threshold value (5) in the WMS url. But I didn't find an example how to make that threshold dynamic.

Comment: Can you add the working sld for the first part to the question

Comment: I added the sld part (it doesn't contain the same values but the idea is the same). Do you know how I can pass the threshold value by variable substitution?

Comment: Just put the env function in where the 5s are?

Comment: thanks :) I didn't know that's so easy, I can' mark your comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the env function almost anywhere an expression is allowed in your SLD so your example becomes:

```
<CssParameter name="stroke">
  <ogc:Function name="Interpolate">
    <ogc:PropertyName>VALUE</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Literal>-9999</ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:Literal>#000000</ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:Literal>#000000</ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:Literal>#A51C1C</ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:Literal>
       <ogc:Function name="env">
          <ogc:Literal>break</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
       </ogc:Function>
    </ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:Literal>#FF9A9A</ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Function name="env">
            <ogc:Literal>break</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
    </ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:Literal>#00FF00</ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:Literal>color</ogc:Literal>
```

Assuming you have a variable called break it will be inserted, and if not then the default value of 5 will be used.